# Where do you put your knockoutjs observable extensions

Tags: unit-testing, mvvm, knockout.js, requirejs

When you use knockoutjs with requirejs and follow the MVVM pattern and you implement such a knockoutjs array extension where do you put this?

Directly in the ViewModel where it is used?

Or in an extra javascript file like ObservableExtensions.js and you inject with requirejs just like you do it maybe with custom bindinghandlers?

```
ko.observableArray.fn.doSomething = function(other) {

};
```

Comment: Personally, I always put these type of things into separate files (like bindings) rather than with a specific view model.

Answer (score 0):

Like, @RP Niemeyer commented, I also put separate bindings, extensions, and view models. Reason being it allows for a more modular design of front end code. You never know when you will need to reuse functionality. It also allows me to write separate unit tests specifically for bindings, extensions and view models without testing how they interact with each other, essentially breaking them down into the smallest units possible.

```
\js
\js\tests
\js\tests\knockoutExtensionTests
\js\tests\jqueryExtensionTests
\js\tests\firstBindingTest.js
\js\tests\secondBindingTest.js
\js\tests\firstVmTest.js
\js\tests\secondVmTest.js
\js\extensions
\js\extensions\knockoutExtension.js
\js\extensions\jqueryExtensions.js
\js\bindings
\js\bindings\firstBinding.js
\js\bindings\secondBinding.js
\js\viewmodels
\js\viewmodels\firstVM.js
\js\viewmodels\secondVM.js
```

I also wouldn't limit it to ONLY knockout extensions because you never know when you may need to extend another library like jQuery to add more functionality. This may seem like a lot of files to load individually but with the bundling and minification tools out there currently, in production you won't hardly notice.